# Run soffice.bin through supervisor

Tags: java, openoffice.org, libreoffice, supervisord

My supervisor conf:

```
[program:libre]
user = myuser
directory = /user/home/directory
command = /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin "--accept=socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=9000,tcpNoDelay=1;urp;" --headless --nodefault --nofirststartwizard --nolockcheck --nologo --norestore
stdout_logfile= /var/log/libreoffice-headless.log
redirect_stderr = true
autostart = true
```

soffice.bin does not start under the user "myuser".
Here is the error log:

> ```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::uno::RuntimeException'
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'com::sun::star::uno::RuntimeException'
> ```

**But if i run command in the console under the "myuser", it starts.**

Comment: What user are you launching supervisord as? Can you try setting environment=HOME=/home/myuser in the config? soffice needs HOME env variable to be set. You may find this link relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034709/incorrect-user-for-supervisord-celeryd